# PHP Calling just part of string item

Tags: php

So I have not yet learned PHP but our guy that would normally write the functions for our site is busy. So I'm attempting to solve this problem with very limited knowledge. I need to convert 4 digit army time (0800, 0815, 0830, 0845, 0900...) into standard time (8:00AM, 8:15AM,...). I wrote an equation but its returning all the hours as 12 and always PM. Here's my equation...

```
function convert_army_to_regular($time) {
    $hours = substr($time, 0, 1);
    $minutes = substr($time, 2, 3);

    if ($hours > 12) { 
        $hours = $hours - 12;
        $ampm = 'PM';
    } else if ($hours = 12) {
           $ampm = 'PM';
    } else {
        if ($hours < 11){
        $ampm = 'AM';
        }
    }

  return $hours . ':' . $minutes . $ampm;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `else if ($hours = 12)` is an assignment, you want a comparison `else if ($hours == 12)`. I also think you have your substr lengths wrong. Check them with the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Now it's returning all 0 for the hour, and I used that manual to pick the substr lengths but I don't really understand them. It says 0 is the first position, so I was thinking the first number would be 0, the second 1, and so on.

Comment: That did it thank you. I wasn't understanding what the values represented. I thought I listed the positions I wanted to display. Thank you!!

Comment: Is there a way to display only the 1st number of times earlier than 10am. For example, 8:00am instead of 08:00am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with your code, `=` is an assignment. You need to use `==` for a comparison (or `===` would also work, that checks the type as well).

The second issue is the `substr`. That function takes the position to start as parameter 1 and the number of characters to advance as 2. So your second parameter should be 2, in both examples.

```
$hours = substr($time, 0, 2);
$minutes = substr($time, 2, 2);
```

You also can cast it to an `int` and that will remove the leading `0` if it is less than 10.

```
$hours = (int)substr($time, 0, 2);
```

You also could do this with a regex:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\d{2})(\d{2})/', function($match) {
    $hours = (int)$match[1];
    $minutes = $match[2];
    $median = 'AM';
    if($hours > 12 ) {
        $hours = $hours - 12;
        $median = 'PM';
    } 
    return $hours . ':' . $minutes . $median;
},'1800');
```

Comment: preg_replace seems like major overkill for something so simple that may be accomplish with built in functions.

Comment: @Dave Seems like a waste of a downvote, since the answer actual explains the issue to the OP. I also doubt it would be a "major" performance issue, maybe milliseconds, at best.

Comment: `Date = .0000650883 seconds, Regex = 0.0001711845` https://3v4l.org/V7g4q

Comment: Thanks for that .... the point I was trying to make was about simplicity, readability and maintainability that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `date` to convert from military to standard time:

```
$armyTime = "2300";
$time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($armyTime));
echo $time_in_12_hour_format;
```

**Result:** 11:00 pm

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to leverage the strtotime function and date.

```
$stime = '0830';

echo date("g:ia", strtotime($stime));
```

which results in 8:30am